# How to write a real memory leak program on windows?

Tags: memory-leaks

I found that without the release of crt-malloc/winapi-heapfunc, 
at the end of the current process, the operating system will 
automatically clean up this part of the memory that has not been released
[my question]:
After the process is really leaked, not recycled
Is that possible? If so, please give an example

Comment: Why do you wonder? What is the actual problem you have?

Comment: Oh, and please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You probably can't. When a process quits, the system frees all of it's memory.

Comment: @Some programmer dude I am really sorry for my friend, why is that so many people even write C language will not take the initiative to release the memory, even if they know it is the same with UB. So I want to try to find a few examples to the contrary. This forum I use, I'm really sorry.

Comment: Try this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551(v=vs.85).aspx and remove the unmapping of buffers and closing of handles.

Comment: @MichaelWalz thanks

Comment: @alk I have looked and experimented,this code try to use named kernel objects to keep the memory of the operating system within the scope of the life cycle, but when I end the process when the memory still be freed,-very strange! (But still Thank you for your inspiring code)

Comment: as alk says, you can do it easily: allocate shared memory, and don't release it. This way you can create a real memory leak. But for simple heap allocations, the OS will release it at process exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible without knowledge of how the os memory management works.

If you knew, you could try to mess with the os's memory bookkeeping, but you probably just break the complete computer.

One alternative: install MsDos 3.2, which had to be rebooted regularly because it didn't perform memory cleanup when programs stopped.

Answer (score 0):

You don't work on real memory in modern Desktop operating systems. They create a virtual memory space which is mapped to real memory. If a process is terminated the OS simply removes the mapping of this process regarding it's real memory as no longer in use.

So no, it is not possible to let a memory leak persist after process termination. If you want, for whatever reason, the memory to stay "leaked" you have to keep your process alive(as a zombie for example).

Comment: only servers fit this example 0_0

Comment: @moecmks why do you think?

Comment: Because servers rarely need to rest, they always maintain high density jobs

Comment: @moecmks I don't know what you are trying to say. memory mapping like this is done by Windows, linux and mac. Even smartphones(android, ios) do this. Only old stuff and some embedded OS use real memory space.

Comment: You're right, my understanding is wrong. I'm just a rookie from China. A lot of troubles that make you confused, please forgive me. (and the guy upstairs is also)